# API calls are blocking other touchables in the screen - React Native

Tags: react-native, axios, touchableopacity

When a API call is happening, Im not able to click any touchables in the screen. They wont respond until the API call is done. Is there any solution for this?

I tried with many react native components like TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, Pressable but the main issue is onPress itself is not trigger when the API call is in process.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `async`/`await` or `.then` while making api calls. if you are not using these your app will stop working until api call completes or promise resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the dev tool and set `show perf monitor` on and check the JS FPS?

Async functions usually don't block touchables while they are running in the background. Regardless if you use `async/await` or `.then`.

According to what you have provided, it seems that your JS thread is freezing which means there are many processes running in the background.

Can you please share a snippet of the code you are running?